# How to specializing a forwarding parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I'm making use of a generic class member to forward a variable list of arguments to an external object, using *forwarding arguments*:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class MyClass {
 public:
    MyClass() = default;
    virtual ~MyClass() = default;

    // ...

    template < typename... Args >
    void func(Args&&... args);
};


// generic definition
template < typename... Args >
void MyClass::func(Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "MyClass::" << __func__ << std::endl;
    // ...
    // e.g. Other(std::forward< Args >(args)...);
    // ...
}
```

However, I'd like to account for a specific case associated with a specific signature for `func` e.g. `func(float, const std::string&)`. However, I'm not entirely sure how to specialize the template to account for arguments to be passed by-value and by-reference.

I'm only able to compile a specialized definition for `func` that uses *rvalue* references:

```
// specialization
template <  >
void MyClass::func< float&&, std::string&& >(float&& first, std::string&& rest) {
    std::cout << "MyClass::" << __func__  << "(float,std::string)" << std::endl;
}
```

However, whereas the generic forwarding definition would be called for any combination of argument types, this specialization will only fit temporary objects. I assume the issue is related to the use of `&&` on the template declaration, but how would one specialize for different combinations of `(float, const std::string&)` arguments?

Comment: Is there a reason for not adding an overload or selecting paths in one function body via `if constexpr` and type traits? Does it have to be a specialization?

Comment: @user17732522 I'd still like to provide a generic implementation w/ a parameter pack (as I'm forwarding the arguments to an overloaded function), and as far as I know the generic template would effectively shadow any non-template overload.

Comment: No, it is the other way around. The more specialized a function template is, the higher is its priority in overload resolution. (The details are a bit complicated though.) Non-templates are always preferred over templates given that the conversions required on the arguments are not already deciding in favor of one or the other.

Comment: `float, const std::string&` cannot specialize `Args&&...`, but `float&&, const std::string&` can

Comment: I ran into similar issues in the past where I had to overload for `&` and `&&` arguments to escape the generic variadic template a instead of just `const &` and ever since stayed away from such implementations

Answer (score 1):

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8jx5fKrY4)

I can only think of this solution that uses a helper template class. The class method punts the job to a helper template class, using `std::remove_cvref_t` to trim off the fat:

```
template < typename... Args >
void func(Args&&... args)
{
    helper<std::remove_cvref_t<Args>...>::func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And this now becomes mostly bog-standard specialization:

```
template<typename ...Args2> struct helper {

    template<typename ...Args>
    static void func(Args && ...args)
    {
        std::cout << "Generic\n";
    }
};

template<> struct helper<double, std::string> {

    template<typename ...Args>
    static void func(Args && ...args)
    {
        std::cout << "Specialized\n";
    }
};
```

With the following test code:

```
    double v=0;
    std::string s;

    func(v, v);
    func(v, s);
    func(v, std::move(s));
```

The result is:

```
Generic
Specialized
Specialized
```

Now, if all the real work needs to be done by a class method, what can be done is have `func()` pass along `*this` as the first parameter to the static `func()`s, which then use it to forwards their remaining argument to two real class methods -- generic and specialized.

It is a reasonable bet that modern compilers will be able to optimize away the extra function calls, this is par for the course in modern C++.